# Ignoring NaN from summation

Tags: c#, nan

I want to sum up 10 double variables, however some of these variables may contain "NaN". Is there a way to ignore the ones with "NaN" from the summation. Right now I have a simple addition like below, however it assigns the SumLiq.. variable an "NaN" value.

```
double SumLiqPerTimeStamp = l2_msg.size0 + l2_msg.size1 + l2_msg.size2 + l2_msg.size3
                           +l2_msg.size4 + l2_msg.size5 + l2_msg.size6 + l2_msg.size7 +  l2_msg.size8 + l2_msg.size9;
```

Is there a fast efficient way to check for "NaN"'s without going through an if statement for each?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NMaybe you can put them in an array and get the `Sum()` :

```
double SumLiqPerTimeStamp = new double[]{ l2_msg.size0 , l2_msg.size1 , l2_msg.size2 , l2_msg.size3
                       ,l2_msg.size4 , l2_msg.size5 , l2_msg.size6 , l2_msg.size7 ,  l2_msg.size8 , l2_msg.size9 }.Where( x => !double.IsNaN(x) ).Sum();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an extension method that returns zero if input is NaN:

```
public static double Value(this double input)
{
    return input == Double.NaN ? 0 : input;
}
```

then sum your values as

```
var sum = l2_msg.size0.Value() + l2_msg.size1.Value() + ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a property `Size` to your `msg` type, which will check the value before returning, and return 0 in case of NaN.

Comment: I can't edit the class it's an api I'm using for a vendors product @Eugene Sh.

Comment: You can always make a wrapper, but it might be an overshoot.